# JavaScript to flatten nested JSON object based on key value

Tags: javascript, json, object

Any suggestions on how to update below JSON object as expected one in Javascript?

Have been trying to flatten JSON object based on JSON key,

- ..outer_component[x] contains section{} then moved to outer_component[x].outer_body.outer_component[x]
- ..outer_component[x] contains outer_body{} then keep on iterate till it reaches section{} and move outer_component[x].outer_body.outer_component[x]

**Received JSON Object:**

```
{
  "document": {
    "outer_component": [
      {
        "outer_body": {
          "outer_component": [
            {
              "outer_body": {
                "outer_component": [
                  {
                    "section": {
                      "id": [
                        {
                          "root": "INNER_11"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "section": {
                      "id": [
                        {
                          "root": "INNER_12"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "outer_body": {
                "outer_component": [
                  {
                    "section": {
                      "id": [
                        {
                          "root": "INNER_21"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "section": {
                      "id": [
                        {
                          "root": "INNER_22"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "outer_body": {
          "outer_component": [
            {
              "outer_body": {
                "outer_component": [
                  {
                    "outer_body": {
                      "outer_component": [
                        {
                          "outer_body": {
                            "outer_component": [
                              {
                                "section": {
                                  "id": [
                                    {
                                      "root": "INNER_31"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "section": {
                                  "id": [
                                    {
                                      "root": "INNER_32"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "outer_body": {
                            "outer_component": [
                              {
                                "section": {
                                  "id": [
                                    {
                                      "root": "INNER_33"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "section": {
                                  "id": [
                                    {
                                      "root": "INNER_34"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "document": {
        "outer_component": [{
            "section": {
                "id": [{
                    "root": "INNER_11"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "section": {
                "id": [{
                    "root": "INNER_12"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "section": {
                "id": [{
                    "root": "INNER_21"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "section": {
                "id": [{
                    "root": "INNER_22"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "section": {
                "id": [{
                    "root": "INNER_31"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "section": {
                "id": [{
                    "root": "INNER_32"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "section": {
                "id": [{
                    "root": "INNER_33"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "section": {
                "id": [{
                    "root": "INNER_34"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: by not using JSON. Step 1: turn it into normal JS data. Step 2: do normal JS things. Step 3: turn that back into JSON. The only thing you do with JSON is parse it, or send it, because JSON is just a string. So show the code you've already written for part 2 in your post, and talk about what you expected all the parts of that code to do, which part(s) didn't do what you expected, and what you already did in terms of debugging and (re)searching solutions.

Comment: As mentioned,  use JSON.parse() to turn JSON into a JavaScript object, so you can use normal JavaScript methods to work with it, and then JSON.stringify() to turn the JavaScript object back to JSON.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you Mike, Yes I did on JS but failed to mention it on question while posting. I'm sorry for that.

Had posted a solution (to my knowledge), Could you please provide feedback when you get chance

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with other users comments but you can also give a try to below code,

```
  const result = {
  document: {
    outer_component: inputJSON.document.outer_component.map((outerComponent) => {
      return {
        outer_body: {
          outer_component: outerComponent.outer_body.outer_component.reduce(
            (acc, innerComponent) => {
              const sections = innerComponent.outer_body
                ? innerComponent.outer_body.outer_component.reduce(
                    (acc, sectionComponent) => {
                      if (sectionComponent.section) {
                        acc.push(sectionComponent.section);
                      }
                      return acc;
                    },
                    []
                  )
                : [];

              return [...acc, ...sections];
            },
            []
          ),
        },
      };
    }),
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var doc_obj = {
  "document": {
    "outer_component": [
      {
        "outer_body": {
          "outer_component": [
            {
              "outer_body": {
                "outer_component": [
                  {
                    "section": {
                      "id": [
                        {
                          "root": "INNER_11"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "section": {
                      "id": [
                        {
                          "root": "INNER_12"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "outer_body": {
                "outer_component": [
                  {
                    "section": {
                      "id": [
                        {
                          "root": "INNER_21"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "section": {
                      "id": [
                        {
                          "root": "INNER_22"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "outer_body": {
          "outer_component": [
            {
              "outer_body": {
                "outer_component": [
                  {
                    "outer_body": {
                      "outer_component": [
                        {
                          "outer_body": {
                            "outer_component": [
                              {
                                "section": {
                                  "id": [
                                    {
                                      "root": "INNER_31"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "section": {
                                  "id": [
                                    {
                                      "root": "INNER_32"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "outer_body": {
                            "outer_component": [
                              {
                                "section": {
                                  "id": [
                                    {
                                      "root": "INNER_33"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "section": {
                                  "id": [
                                    {
                                      "root": "INNER_34"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

//Dynamic Components
var dyn_component = dynamic_document(
    doc_obj,
    "section", 
    []
)

//Assigning constructed Dynamic Components
doc_obj["document"]["dyn_component"] = dyn_component

//Delete Outer Component
delete doc_obj["document"]["outer_component"]

console.log(JSON.stringify(doc_obj))

/*
Function: To dynamically fetch component's section
*/
function dynamic_document(
    doc, req_component, sections
) {
    if (doc != null) {
        if (Array.isArray(doc)) {
            doc.forEach((arrayItem) => {
                dynamic_document(arrayItem, req_component, sections);
            });
        } else if (typeof doc == 'object') {
            Object.keys(doc).forEach((key) => {
                if (key == req_component) {
                    sections.push(doc);
                } else {
                    dynamic_document(doc[key], req_component, sections);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return sections;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).